# extract data between two time range from MySQL using python

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to fetch data from mysql database through python and I want to print it, but it give me nothing. My code is as follow

```
import time
import datetime
import calendar
import mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='xxxx', password='xxxx',
                                  database='robbinDatabase')
    cursor = cnx.cursor()
    tableData = cursor.execute('select * from robtable')
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    print 'data: ', data
```

the above code works quite well, but I dont want to fetch all data from a table. I am trying to extract in a particular time range, so I try like this

```
   cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='xxxx', password='xxxx',
                                  database='robbinDatabase')
   cursor = cnx.cursor()
   rowsdata = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM robtable WHERE usec BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2016-02-25') AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2016-02-26 23:59:59')")
   # rowsdata = cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM robtable WHERE usec BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(1456411800000000) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(1456416000000000)')
   # rowsdata = cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM robtable WHERE  `robin.col1.data` BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME(1456411800) AND FROM_UNIXTIME(145642200)')
   data = cursor.fetchall()
   print data
```

and the result is

```
data: []
```

It return me nothing.

the data in my table for usec columns and two other columns look like this

```
usec               robin.col1.data    robin.col2.data
1456411800000000    10.90             8.02
1456412400000000    22.3              33
.
.
.
.
1469950200000000    12.22             32.43
```

usec is a column which contains timestamp but in epoch timeformat with microseconds. I also tried with other column e.g `robin.col1.data` 
If somebody help me, I would be grateful.

Comment: Can you attach an example of one value from usec ?

Comment: @TzlilPha yes sure, I will edit my question in a momen, and will add some values of the columns in my table.

Comment: @TzlilPha I add some data in the question from my table.

Answer (score 1):

You should try:
    date(FROM_UNIXTIME(epoch) 
    instaed of UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2016-02-25')

try run in your sql:
    SELECT date(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())));

Comment: I am trying to fetch data in the python.

Comment: I know but you are sending you'r query like that:    rowsdata = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM robtable WHERE usec BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2016-02-25') AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2016-02-26 23:59:59')") so just change to FROM_UNIXTIME()

Comment: Don't forget to put inside FROM_UNIXTIME(epoch). epoch is the date in timestamp

Comment: But I if put (epoch) then how date or time range can be given?........I tried like this but results is still None . .'rowsdata = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM robtable WHERE usec BETWEEN  FROM_UNIXTIME('2016-02-25') AND  FROM_UNIXTIME('2016-02-26 23:59:59')")'

Comment: It will not help you. the values that you save in usec are not good. they are long too much. how do you get the timestamp?

Comment: No. 'rowsdata = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM robtable WHERE usec BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME(put here the usec value you need) AND FROM_UNIXTIME(put here the usec value you need)")'

Comment: the timestamp is '2016-02-25 14:50:00' , but before storing in mysql I change it to '1456411800000000'  as per our requirements. .

Comment: Ok I will try now according your instructions. .

Comment: How do you change the date into timestamp? something is not good there. if you try:    SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()),"%Y-%m-%d"); it will work just fine.

Comment: you mean like this . rowsdata = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM robtable WHERE usec BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME('2016-02-25 14:50:00') AND FROM_UNIXTIME('2016-02-25 16:20:00')")    right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142819/discussion-between-tzlilpha-and-robbin).